# Using Cygwin for FFMPEG build error cmp: command not found

Tags: windows, bash, ffmpeg, cygwin

I've been trying to use Cygwin to build ffmpeg but I'm running into the error `./configure: line 1132: cmp: command not found`. I tried looking around online for solutions but found none. I also checked if I just didn't download the right package when I downloaded Cygwin but I found nothing relating to cmd. I'm not sure if there is a workaround or not. The code from line 1132 is: 
`cp_if_changed(){
    cmp -s "$1" "$2" && echo "$2 is unchanged" && return
    mkdir -p "$(dirname $2)"
    $cp_f "$1" "$2"
}`

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want to install the cygwin [diffutils](http://cygwin.com/packages/x86/diffutils/) package.

Comment: Yep there it is. Thanks